# Apache POI parse and handle empty cells

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi

I am using a java servlet to parse an uploaded excel file,

I get the file as and input stream and make the workbook, and then I want to loop though all the cells including the empty ones, right now this is what I am doing, this handles empty cells in the middle of the data, but if there is a row that is completely empty and then a row with data after it fails

```
for (int i = 0; i < mySheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    Row row = mySheet.getRow(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); j++) {
          Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
    }
}
```

So it these are my rows

```
item item item
               //this row is empty
item item item
```

It is failing how can I handle this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you not use `getFirstRowNum` and `getLastRowNum` (same for columns)

Comment: @ScaryWombat this helped me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If row fectching and get back null, then there is no data stored in the file for that row - it's completely blank.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mySheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    Row row = mySheet.getRow(i);
    for (int c = row.getFirstCellNum(); c < row.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
           Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
        if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
        .....
    }
}
```

and check poi example [POI Example](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)